# Auth0 and Stripe integration

Tags: flask, stripe-payments, auth0

I am creating a Flask webapp that uses Auth0 to handle user sign-ups. I am also looking to monetize my app with the Stripe API. I have followed this tutorial (https://developer.auth0.com/resources/labs/actions/sync-stripe-customers-and-auth0-users#introduction) to sync stripe customers and auth0 users, such that whenever a new auth0 user is created, it also creates a stripe customer. The Stripe customer ID is stored as app_metadata in auth0, and the auth0 ID is stored as metadata for the Stripe user.

However, I am having trouble with retrieving the Stripe customer ID from a given auth0 ID inside my Flask application. Ideally, when I am ready to create a Stripe checkout session, I could easily retrieve the app-metadata from my Auth0 user to find the associated stripe customer ID. I have tried using the Auth0 manager API, but I am a bit confused because it seems that the token I need to use the API expires every 24 hours.

I was also thinking of storing my Auth0 ID and stripe ID into an AWS RDS database upon user creation. However, I am also having trouble connecting to my database inside an Auth0 action.

What are the best practices for my scenario?